# How to remove full footer from odoo10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am using odoo10 community edition .
I try to remove full footer

```
<template id="default_footer_remove" inherit_id="website.footer_custom">
        <xpath expr="//div[@id='footer']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="t-att-style">'display: none;'</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

This is my code .  it will remove the contents .
[image]

This is the footer before execute .

[image]
This is the image after execute.

**How to remove full footer ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to completely hide or remove the footer you should give the attribute to the parent tag: `<footer>` not to inner one.

Here is the footer part of default Odoo website layout:

```
<footer>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</footer>
```

So, you should give attribute to `footer` tag. In this piece of code I directly replace it with nothing:

```
<template id="default_footer_remove" inherit_id="website.layout">
    <xpath expr="//footer" position="replace">
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: Position="attributes" and use like this  <attribute name="style">display: none;</attribute> is much better .

Comment: Both ways work. It's up to you which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could remove the footer in Odoo 10 using the XML templating engine:

```
<template id="website.footer_custom" inherit_id="website.footer_custom" 
          name="Remove Footer" priority="1" >
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='footer']" position="replace">
        <div style="display: none;"></div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

This code uses the template tag with the id attribute set to "website.footer_custom" and inherit_id attribute set to "website.footer_custom" so it will override the existing template, and the xpath tag is then used to target the div element with the id "footer" and replace it with an empty div with a style attribute set to "display: none;", which effectively hides the footer from the website.

You would need to add this to a XML file inside an Odoo module and then install that module in Odoo.

Please note that this code will remove the entire footer, including all its content.

Comment: Thanks for replay but the code not working properly , 
'<xpath expr="//div[@id='footer']">' cannot be located in parent view.
I got this error while adding you code